# Spring boot Apache kafka binder project, application.properties spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder. jaas properties are unknown

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kerberos

my project application.properties give warning. saying

> 'spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.jaas.loginModule' is an unknown
>   property.

my project .pom file is given below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.shiwantha.test</groupId>
<artifactId>KafkaTestOne</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.RC2</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-kafka.version>1.1.1.RELEASE</spring-kafka.version>
    <spring-integration-kafka.version>2.1.0.RELEASE</spring-integration-kafka.version>
    <kafka.version>0.10.0.0</kafka.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <!-- spring-boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.RC2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>

        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>

        <scope>test</scope>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>



<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- spring-boot-maven-plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone-local</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/release</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I want to create a spring boot kafka consumer application which communicate with  kafka cluster which is secured by using kerberos. i have keytab file. and kafka server informations.

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers = 10.48.148.44,10.48.148.45,10.48.148.46,10.48.148.47
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.autoCommitOffset = false



spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.jaas.loginModule = com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.jaas.controlFlag = required
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.jaas.options.useKeyTab = true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.jaas.options.storeKey = true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.jaas.options.keyTab = src/main/resources/gitcc_kafka_user.keytab       
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.jaas.options.principal = gitcc_kafka_user@DIALOG.DIALOGGSM.COM
```

please help me to overcome these problem.  I am new to this . So please if you can provide sample project which consume kafka server protected by kerberos

Comment: What spring-boot version you are using? You are using 1.1.0 version of the kafka binder? Could you try your application with a later version (1.3.0.RELEASE may be) and see if the issues are still there?

Comment: sobychacko Thank you for response. I used spring boot starter parent 1.5.7 and 1.5.8  with kafka binder 1.3.0.RELEASE. Still  result is same

Comment: @sobychacko  Can you provide a complete pom file which might work without any issues. I have tried many versions combinations of the dependencies. please help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: Works fine for me; see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me; you can see the property being set in the debugger...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class So46903311Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So46903311Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

and

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.jaas.loginModule=testForSo46903311
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=localhost:9092
```

and

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Dalston.SR4</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and

[image: STS Debugger]

Comment: Really sorry my company gave me another urgent project  so i couldn't find the time the check this.  @Gary Russell   now i used   spring kafka 2.0 version for my project.  In that version  there is a  bean for insert jaas configuration.  It solved my authentication problems. Really thank for that version.   But i want to  know, in above solution how you provide  jaas configuration.  And i want to know what is difference between  using apache kafka binder and   spring kafka . I am really new to this field please help me

Comment: I just put the property in `application.properties`. The kafka binder uses `spring-kafka` underneath.